# OpenTK - How to allocate storage for a cubemap array?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I need to create a cubemap array but I am having trouble finding the correct  parameters.

There isn't much in terms of sample code but I did find this, in OpenGL:

```
HiGL_TexStorage3D(
    GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY,
    Data->GetMipMap(),
    DestFormat,
    Data->GetWidth(),
    Data->GetHeight(),
);
```

So it seems the required texture target is `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY`, however OpenTK doesn't list this as an option, only these:

```
GL.TexStorage3D(TextureTarget3d.ProxyTexture2DArray, 0, format, width, height, depth);   
GL.TexStorage3D(TextureTarget3d.ProxyTexture3D, 0, format, width, height, depth);   
GL.TexStorage3D(TextureTarget3d.ProxyTextureCubeMap, 0, format, width, height, depth);   
GL.TexStorage3D(TextureTarget3d.Texture2DArray, 0, format, width, height, depth);   
GL.TexStorage3D(TextureTarget3d.Texture3D, 0, format, width, height, depth); 
GL.TexStorage3D(TextureTarget3d.TextureCubeMap, 0, format, width, height, depth);
```

Can anybody shed some light? [www.opentk.com](http://www.opentk.com) disappeared a few months ago.

Comment: You should file a bug report on this [through their GitHub repo](https://github.com/opentk/opentk).

Comment: Good call, bug reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `GL.TexImage3D` instead, `TextureCubeMapArray` becomes accessable.

```
GL.TexImage3D(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapArray, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rg16, size, size, layers * 6, 0, PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.Float, IntPtr.Zero);
```

The problem was `GL.TexStorage3D` takes a parameter of type `TextureTarget3D`, which does not permit `TextureCubeMapArray`, whereas `GL.TexImage3D` takes `TextureTarget`, which does.

Subsequently, I'm unsure if this still constitutes a bug, or how these two functions differ.